# C#: Draw a line in SharpDX (Direct3D11)

Tags: c#, rendering, directx-11, sharpdx, line-drawing

i just can not figure out how to draw some lines for a grid in my sharpdx scene. I saw some samples for the Direct3D9 but i am using Direct3D11 so i can not get it working. 
The Line class that is provided in DirectDX3D9 is not supported in Direct3D11.
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35R5V.png)

I thought of creating something like little scaled cubes for a line instead but i think that is not the right way to do this because i would have 8 Vertices for a line instead of 2.

Comment: Do you need lines of a certain thickness, or will 1-pixel-wide lines do?  If the latter, you can still draw single-pixel-wide lines using `PrimitiveTopology.LineStrip`...

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for, thank you. Could you provide an example for the usage?